# How to get nodes with term programmatically

Tags: 7, database

I have Vocabulary and Custom Content Type which has field Term reference.

How can I get all nodes of particular term in my module?

Something like this? This doesn't work.

```
$field = field_info_field('field_game');
$results = new EntityFieldQuery;
$results->fieldCondition($field, 'field_game_tid', '5')
  ->execute();

$nids = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
  $nids[] = $result->nid;
}

$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to specify that you searching for nodes first (and optionally by your content type), and then filter by term:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_HERE')
->fieldCondition('field_game', 'tid', 5);

$result = $query->execute();
$nids = array_keys($result['node']);
$nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
```

Here's a good [example of an entity query](http://drupal.org/node/1343708) like this (and more field conditions)

Answer (score 4):

There is an API function [`taxonomy_select_nodes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7.x) for that:

```
$tid = 5;
$nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, FALSE); // FALSE for paging.
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```